# Differentiable function $f:\left[ {0,8} \right] \to R$

Tags: calculus

If the function $f:\left[ {0,8} \right] \to R$ is differentiable then for $0 < \alpha ,\beta  < 2$ , $\int\limits_0^8 {f\left( t \right)dt} $ is equal to

(A) $3\left[ {{\alpha ^3}f\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right) + {\beta ^3}f\left( {{\beta ^2}} \right)} \right]$

(B) $3\left[ {{\alpha ^3}f\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right) + {\beta ^3}f\left( \beta  \right)} \right]$

(C) $3\left[ {{\alpha ^2}f\left( {{\alpha ^3}} \right) + {\beta ^2}f\left( {{\beta ^3}} \right)} \right]$

(D) $3\left[ {{\alpha ^2}f\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right) + {\beta ^2}f\left( {{\beta ^2}} \right)} \right]$

My solution is as follow $T\left( x \right) = \int\limits_0^{{x^3}} {f\left( t \right)dt} $

$T'\left( x \right) = f\left( {{x^3}} \right).3{x^2}$

Not able to approach from here

Comment: Should the limits on the integral be $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Or perhaps $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$?

Comment: I copied the question as per the books I presume that $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=0$